# Mac App Submission Checklist

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, interface-builder

I'm aware Apple has a submission checklist they released on their website a few months ago, however, I'm looking for a more detailed list (i.e. "Add Copyright (human-readable) to Plist file" etc) that contains the little stuff an app needs before it is submitted. Anyone have a link, or fancy writing one out? I don't think there's TOO many, but they're little things that could get an app rejected

Zach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe Craig Hockenberry's detailed guide for Mac App Store submissions, could help: [Mac App Store guide](http://furbo.org/2011/03/09/mac-app-store-guide/)

Answer (score 1):

**Cong** is a tool to check the resources of the bundle of your application to look for common errors or typo. It's better than a checklist: it is an automated checklist that performs the verifications for you.

It works for Mac application, framework or Preferences Pane and iOS application.

It checks many points for you:

- in your files hierarchy (missing files, incorrect file type)
- validity of your Info.plist file
- common typos in your .strings files
- useless header files that should be stripped out during the copy files phase
- etc

See the complete checklist here: http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Cong/tech_specs.html

Free tool.
Check out **Cong** at http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Cong/about.html